# rqt_reconfigure resets parameters on startup

Tags: ros, rqt-reconfigure, rqt, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I had serious problems with saving and loading parameter while using rqt_reconfigure. To find my problem I broke the code down to the following:

1. Start the node with the dynamic_reconfigure server
2. rosparam set /node_name/myparam 42
3. rosparam get /node_name/myparam (returns 42 and everything works)
4. rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure
5. rosparam get /node_name/myparam (returns value saved in .cfg file)

I do not know why rqt_reconfigure does that. I also checked out its wiki page and as far as I see it should read the values from the parameter server and not set them back to the default from the .cfg file. I am lost.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99071/rqt_reconfigure-resets-parameters-on-startup/) by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1554 on 2013-11-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was just trolling through and found this question, which is a little old. Hopefully this info will be useful to someone.

I found this issue when I took over maintenance a couple of months ago, and fixed it soon after. Please try pulling the latest version of rqt_reconfigure from rqt_common_plugins at https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins

The fix is not in the current release, but will certainly be in the next one.

---

Originally posted by [cottsay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3167/cottsay/) with karma: 311 on 2014-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2014-04-24**:
Thanks a lot for fixing it!